# Create list of objects for use by ObjectListView [python]

Tags: python, list, objectlistview

I'm new to classes and to the python module ObjectListView.
I wish to create a text-editable window using ObjectListView, but the example I'm basing my work on requires the objects which each define text entries of a multi-columned row, should be accessible in a list such as this:

> names = [MyClass("James", "Cameron"),
>              MyClass("Samantha", "Jones")]

(Note that quotation marks only bookend the first name and surnames of each entry).

I currently hold my names in a standard dictionary which is in this format:

> namesDict = { "James":"Cameron",
>                       "Samantha":"Jones"}

My attempt to convert my dictionary into the format required is here:

```
namesDict = { "James":"Cameron","Samantha":"Jones"}
out = []
for key in namesDict:
out.append("MyClass(\""+key+"\",\""+namesDict[key]+"\")")
print(out)
```

My code leaves me with the following product, which is all good EXCEPT for the single quotation marks around each entry in the list:

> ['MyClass("James","Cameron")','MyClass("Samantha","Jones")']

I'm not sure how to get rid of these single quotes. I'm also assuming that there may be a standard technique to make objects from dictionaries which I'm simply not aware of?

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about the single-quotes - that's how python represents strings. If you were to do `print(out[0])`, the single-quotes would disappear.

Comment: I would be very suprised if that was close to working. `out.append("MyClass(\""+key+"\",\""+namesDict[key]+"\")")` creates a string literal, while `names = [MyClass("James", "Cameron"), MyClass("Samantha", "Jones")]` looks like a list of actual instances of `MyClass`. I don't use the library myself but I don't see why it would expect strings.

Comment: The quote marks indicate that you're dealing with string literals, as that's what you've passed to the `out` list. Assuming your `MyClass` constructor takes two arguments, wouldn't it be: `out.append(MyClass(key, namesDict[key])`? That will create an instance of `MyClass` for each item in the `namesDict`.

Comment: @roganjosh I think you're right that it requires a list of instances and not a list of strings (which is all I am managing to produce). That's my problem. How can I produce a list of instances from my original dictionary? I will update my question with better phraseology.

Comment: @DavidZemens - I'll give it a go!

Comment: As David has suggested in their comment. Where is `MyClass` defined?

Comment: @thescoop see my comment :) but it will not *print* the way you expect unless you override the `MyClass.__str__`

Comment: As a side note, `namesDict = { "James":"Cameron", "Samantha":"Jones"}` is a really unusual data structure. Unless you needed to quickly find surnames from first names, it doesn't make sense to have a dictionary with keys and values like this. Especially since first names are quite commonly shared, and duplicate first names will just overwrite the surname stored against the first name

Comment: I have written a program which uses a dictionary. I have just decided to implement a GUI too, and for this, I'm using wx python and ObjectListView which requires me to convert my dictionary into a list of instances. I will attempt @DavidZemens out.append(MyClass(key, namesDict[key]) suggestion and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote marks indicate that you're dealing with string literals, as that's what you've passed to the out list. Assuming your `MyClass` constructor takes two arguments, you can add an instance to your list like:

```
out.append(MyClass(key, namesDict[key])
```

However, this won't *print* the way you expect, it will use the `object.__str__` which returns `object.__repr__()`:

```
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x000002571A58B400>
```

You can override this in your class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ + '("' + '","'.join([str(v) for k,v in vars(self).items()]) + '")'
```

And then the instances of `MyClass` will be printed neatly:

```
>>> m = MyClass('James','Cameron')
>>> print(m)
MyClass("James", "Cameron")
```